# Auto print google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a need for a programming script that I believe is relatively simple, but I don't even have the slightest background in programming so I'm lost. I have a spreadsheet in google docs.On the page I want to print there is a validated cell that can be clicked on in order to select a "campaign name" once selected, there are two graphs below that populate based on data on another sheet.

I'm looking to make a formula that selects the first option in the list, waits 15 seconds (for it to calculate), prints the page, then goes on to the 2nd option, waits 15 seconds, prints, ect... until it has gone through the entire list. Does anyone know how I might go about this, or if not where I could start? I know google docs uses Google apps script which is based off of javascript. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is not able to print anything, you should remember that scripts run on Google's server (cloud) and has no access to your hardware.

The best you could do would be to generate PDF files in a dedicated folder and then print these pdf yourself manually.